# Rails 4 Delayed_Paperclip File Upload S3 Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_paperclip to asynchronously upload images to S3. However, it seems to always load the original image size first, causing a long delay, and for the other image styles I get the response: AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey No Such Key

model.rb:

```
has_attached_file :asset, 
    :styles => { large: "800x800>", medium: "500x500>", small: "200x200>", thumb: "40x40#" },
    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'X',
    :s3_credentials => {XY}

process_in_background :asset
```

Delayed_Job is included and the columns are added to the models:

```
t.boolean  "asset_processing"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am renaming my attachment's filename in a `before_save` method to obfuscate it. File renaming works fine without `delayed_paperclip`, but with the delayed process the file renaming didn't work as expected and the path to the file was screwed up, producing your AWS error.

I believe `delayed_paperclip` uploads the original, then refetches it for processing later because the original in local storage is no longer there. **I moved this renaming code to `paperclip`s `before_post_process` callback and everything works fine.**

Perhaps you are doing something similar? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.
My problem was that I was missing the worker for development purposes.

After running: bundle exec rake jobs:work in my console the rest of the styles were loading up.